# cURL a Tor Hidden Service via Tor's socks5 proxy

Tags: curl, tor

I'm trying to cURL a hidden service via a Tor socks5 proxy. Clearweb links work fine:

```
curl -L -v --socks5-hostname 127.89.1.1:9090 http://google.com
```

But a hidden service url gives an error:

```
curl -L -v --socks5-hostname 127.89.1.1:9090 http://msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion
```

Error message: `curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (6)`

I can reach the website perfectly in the Tor Browser Bundle

Things I have tried:
- syncing server time
- restarting tor

Would someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That exact command and onion URL worked fine for me with cURL 7.47.0 (I had to substitute 127.89.1.1:9090 with the default 127.0.0.1:9050).  What version of Tor and cURL are you running?

Comment: @drew010 I'm using curl 7.47.0 and tor 0.3.1.9 on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: If it's still not working, try adding `Log info file /var/log/tor/tor.log` to your config file and watching the output when you the command.  That may provide hints as to why it can't make the connection to the hidden service.

Comment: @drew010 Unfortuantely the log file does not contain any information related to this problem. Reaching the website works fine in Tor Browser Bundle as well. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Seems like it is having trouble resolving the onion URL which could be a sign of Tor having problems building circuits or talking to directories.  You may need to set the level to `debug` instead of `info` to get the info needed.

Comment: Maybe it's just the site.  As of now, I can't reach it via Tor on the console (other hidden services work fine) nor will it load in Tor Browser.